# Accessing DLLs through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dll

How can I access the functions inside a third-party DLL from VBA (Excel)? Also, is there a way to see what all functions are available inside a DLL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To call a function in a third-party DLL, you need to use the `Declare` statement.  For example:

```
Private Declare Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" _
     Alias "GetTempPathA" (ByVal nBufferLength As Long, _
     ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long
```

See [How to: Access DLLs in Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687915.aspx) on MSDN for more information.

---

To list the functions that are available, take a look at the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) tool, which will list the exported functions from DLLs (and lots of other information).

Comment: kernel32 is a Windows DLL, which VBA can find because the path to WinDir and System32 is included in the environment variable PATH. But when using a third-party DLL, you need to include an absolute path in the Declare statement if your DLL resides in a non-standard location. But if the DLL is registered, can VBA find it vi its CLSID?

Comment: @JamieGarroch-MVP I'm not sure, you may need to ask a new question to get more help